# Photoshop: "Export as" retina resolution pixelated

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, retina

I was trying the latest version of PS and I noticed there a new very useful "Export As" feature capable of exporting multiple Artboards directly in standard and @2x ready png files.

I made an Arboard with 180x90px and imported a big image (1024×545px) as a Smart Object. Then I resized it to fit my Artboard resulting in:

[image]

Then I tried the export feature to create a std size image and a @2x version, using this options:

[image]

As you can see resampling is enabled. This was the output:

[image]
(Click to open in full size)

**So, why is that the last image (2) is pixelated? The image is much smaller than the original image** (1) it should be ok... Is there way I can make photoshop actually resample the image correctly?

Why does it have this behavior? The point of creating a @2x version is to ensure image quality on a high resolution device, not to have a "stretched" version of the std size that will look awful.

Comment: I use CS6 so I've never used it myself but from what I've read it *should* scale smart objects and vector layers correctly... If it doesn't then that makes the whole thing kinda pointless

Comment: @Cai as you can see on the screenshots it looks really pointless. Maybe I'm missing something but...

Comment: have you tried check the exported image in Photoshop? I'm afraid that image preview used by the OS is not correctly place for checking image quality.

Comment: Yes, I did try that. Tried on the browser also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue. Thanks for all the typical useless comments from people who think everyone else is stupid by saying stuff like *"OS image preview sucks"* or want to waste all day doing things that should be automated *"just create the document using the desired @3x and export smaller versions instead of going up"*. I'm disappointed with this SE because this kind low quality of replies aren't found anywhere else on the network.

**There's a bug in PS export** feature where **smart objects made from non-PSD formats won't resample** / resize as needed to avoid the issue I faced.

1. **Convert your original / PNG into a PSD file**;
2. Create a new document you'll be using to export the images with the desired original size (in my case `180x90`px);
3. Use the menu `File > Place...` to place the previous PSD file as a smart object;
4. Export your bigger @2x and @3x versions without issues.

And yes, the image preview on my OS works just fine:

[image]

Comment: The reason your not getting good answers is that there is no info to debug. It attracts all the hairy trolls out of the woodwork.  You dont describe your process so theres nothing one could do to answer the question. But yes sometimes answers suck too...

Comment: -1 for the rant. You can complain about responses but an answer is not the place to rant and all the comments you mention are (if not that helpful) completely valid.

Comment: @joojaa how could I have given more info to debug? I basically described the entire process and added screenshots!

Comment: not all problems are describable, but in this case you didnt describe what your data was like. You described what you did to get data after you put them in PS.